# How to do incrementing and decrementing of a particular product in flutter

Tags: flutter, counter

I'm working on a food delivery app I've tried to make an increment decrement system of a particular product in a list. At the start it works `i.e the counter increases` but a bit after the counter automatically return to `0` without any button press. I don't know why it's happening

**Below is the code I'm trying**

This is the class

```
class ItemData {
  final String itemName;
  final String itemPrice;
  final String image;
  int counter = 0;
  bool isAdded = false;
  ItemData({this.itemName, this.itemPrice, this.image});
}
```

This is the function for getting data from url

```
  Future<List<ItemData>> _getProducts() async {
    var data = await http
        .get("https://orangecitycafe.in/app_configs/products_display.php");

    var jsonData = json.decode(data.body);
    List<ItemData> details = [];
    for (var p in jsonData) {
      ItemData detail = ItemData(
          itemName: p["product_name"],
          itemPrice: p["product_price"],
          image: p["product_image"]);
      details.add(detail);
    }
    return details;
  }
```

This is the code for fetched products inside future builder

```
  Widget _myCart() {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: _getProfile(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return ListTile(
                title: Text(snapshot.data[index].itemName),
                leading: Image.network("https://www.orangecitycafe.in/" +
                    snapshot.data[index].image),
                trailing: snapshot.data[index].isAdded
                    ? Row(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          IconButton(
                            icon: Icon(Icons.remove),
                            onPressed: () {
                              setState(() {
                                if (snapshot.data[index].counter > 0) {
                                  snapshot.data[index].counter--;
                                }
                              });
                            },
                            color: Colors.green,
                          ),
                          Text(snapshot.data[index].counter.toString()),
                          IconButton(
                            icon: Icon(Icons.add),
                            color: Colors.green,
                            onPressed: () {
                              setState(() {
                                snapshot.data[index].counter++;
                              });
                            },
                          ),
                        ],
                      )
                    : RaisedButton(
                      onPressed: (){
                        setState(() {
                          snapshot.data[index].isAdded = true;
                        });
                      },
                      child: Text("Add"),
                    ),
              );
            },
          );
        } else {
          return Container();
        }
      },
    );
  }
```

The rest is working but only when I increase the counter it increases and after sometime it automatically returns to `0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can use the following way to use `Future` in `FutureBuilder` to avoid `setState` cause `FutureBuilder` rebuild again. 
Detail reason https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/11426#issuecomment-414047398 
`didUpdateWidget` of the `FutureBuilder` state is being called every time a rebuild is issued. This function checks if the old future object is different from the new one, and if so, refires the `FutureBuilder`.

To get past this, we can call the `Future` somewhere other than in the build function. For example, in the `initState`, and save it in a member variable, and pass this variable to the `FutureBuilder`.

code snippet

```
Future<List<ItemData>> _future;
...
@override
  void initState() {
    _future = _getProducts();
    super.initState();
  }
...
  Widget _myCart() {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: _future,
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

class ItemData {
  final String itemName;
  final String itemPrice;
  final String image;
  int counter = 0;
  bool isAdded = false;
  ItemData({this.itemName, this.itemPrice, this.image});
}

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  Future<List<ItemData>> _future;

  Future<List<ItemData>> _getProducts() async {
    var data = await http
        .get("https://orangecitycafe.in/app_configs/products_display.php");

    var jsonData = json.decode(data.body);
    List<ItemData> details = [];
    for (var p in jsonData) {
      ItemData detail = ItemData(
          itemName: p["product_name"],
          itemPrice: p["product_price"],
          image: p["product_image"]);
      details.add(detail);
    }
    return details;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _future = _getProducts();
    super.initState();
  }

  Widget _myCart() {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: _future,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return ListTile(
                title: Text(snapshot.data[index].itemName),
                leading: Image.network("https://www.orangecitycafe.in/" +
                    snapshot.data[index].image),
                trailing: snapshot.data[index].isAdded
                    ? Row(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          IconButton(
                            icon: Icon(Icons.remove),
                            onPressed: () {
                              setState(() {
                                if (snapshot.data[index].counter > 0) {
                                  snapshot.data[index].counter--;
                                }
                              });
                            },
                            color: Colors.green,
                          ),
                          Text(snapshot.data[index].counter.toString()),
                          IconButton(
                            icon: Icon(Icons.add),
                            color: Colors.green,
                            onPressed: () {
                              setState(() {
                                snapshot.data[index].counter++;
                              });
                            },
                          ),
                        ],
                      )
                    : RaisedButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          setState(() {
                            snapshot.data[index].isAdded = true;
                          });
                        },
                        child: Text("Add"),
                      ),
              );
            },
          );
        } else {
          return Container();
        }
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
        body: _myCart());
  }
}
```

Comment: It works but when it comes to take a get parameter then it does not returns any data `https://www.orangecitycafe.in/app_configs/my_cart.php?total&user={$takeUsername}` by the way this method of get parameter works normally but is not working when using the above method.

Comment: need to reproduce your case. could you post reproduce code to a new question? thanks.